# $f_n$ converges uniformly on $\overline\Omega$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Suppose $\Omega$ be a bounded region and $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ a sequence of continuous functions on  $\overline\Omega$ which are holomorphic in $\Omega$ and $f_n$ converges uniformly on the boundary of $\Omega$. Prove that $f_n$ converges uniformly on $\overline\Omega$.

How to prove this?

Comment: but how? can you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the  Maximum Principle for Holomorphic functions
$$
\sup_{z\in\overline\Omega}\lvert\,f_m(z)-f_n(z)\rvert=\sup_{z\in\partial\Omega}\lvert\,f_m(z)-f_n(z)\rvert.
$$ 
Hence, if $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $\partial\Omega$, then it is uniformly Cauchy on
$\partial\Omega$, i.e.,
$$
\lim_{m,n\to\infty}\sup_{z\in\partial\Omega}\lvert\,f_m(z)-f_n(z)\rvert=0,
$$
and hence $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly Cauchy on $\overline\Omega$, and thus uniformly convergent on $\overline\Omega$.

Answer (score 1):

For a given $\epsilon >0$, there exists $N$ such that for any $n,m$ greater than $N$, $|f_n(z) - f_m(z)| \leq \epsilon$ on the boundary of $\omega$.

By the [Maximum modulus principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle), $|f_n(z) - f_m(z)|$ can only attain its maximal value on the boundary, so we get $|f_n(z) - f_m(z)| \leq \epsilon$ for all $z \in \bar\omega$